# Makefile: Intel fortran, source files in a folder, and Intel Math Kernel Library

Tags: makefile, fortran, intel-fortran

I have a main.f90 in the folder /ex. And the f77 subroutine files are in /ex/src. And the subroutine files again use BLAS and LAPACK libraries. For the BLAS and LAPACK, I have to use  Intel Math Kernel Library.

The Intel fortran and the mkl folders look like:

```
/opt/intel$
ActivationTool  composer_xe_2011_sp1         intel_sdp_products.db  man
bin             composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339  lib                    mkl
composerxe      include                      licenses

/opt/intel/mkl$
benchmarks  bin  examples  include  interfaces  lib  tests  tools

/opt/intel/mkl/lib/ia32$
libmkl_avx.so             libmkl_gnu_thread.so     libmkl_scalapack_core.so
libmkl_blacs.a            libmkl_intel.a           libmkl_sequential.a
libmkl_blacs_intelmpi.a   libmkl_intel.so          libmkl_sequential.so
libmkl_blacs_intelmpi.so  libmkl_intel_thread.a    libmkl_solver.a
... (a bunch of files) ...
```

What's the makefile code for the main.f90 in /ex to be compiled? Thanks!

Comment: What have you got in your Makefile so far ?

Comment: And how do you compile `main.f90` from the command line (for those of us unfamiliar with fortran)?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using version 12 (guess from `composer_xe_2011_sp1.11.339` in /opt/intel), so you can simply use `-mkl` option when linking like this:

```
ifort main.o sub1.o sub2.o -o a.out -mkl
```

(See: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-mkl-in-intel-compiler-mkl-qmkl-options)