# How can I link MKL to compilation to get missing daxpy_?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I use Ifort ( Intel Compilers 17 (a.k.a Intel® Parallel Studio XE 2017 (Update 4)) and Intel MKL version 11.1.0.080 ) to build old Fortran code using makefile. I work on claster NSC Thriolith. When I try to compile I get mistake.

```
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved daxpy_
        Referenced in /tmp/ipo_ifort1Ub0el.o
```

It is clear to me because I loaded  Intel MKL version 11.1.0.080, but it looks like compiler does not see MKL.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the welcome [tour] and read [ask], also learn how to format your posts. DAXPY is a subroutine from MKL. You must link MKL properly to fix this.

Comment: Vladimir F, hope it's better, can You tell me do I need to put -mkl in makefile? or something other?

Comment: See https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497734/how-to-use-intel-fortran-compiler-with-mkl-on-command-line?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052133/makefile-intel-fortran-source-files-in-a-folder-and-intel-math-kernel-library

Comment: Thank You! I needed to put -mkl=sequential -Nmkl in makefile. Now it works